# Flot Chart - Display Meta Data on Hover

Tags: javascript, metadata, flot

I have a chart that display 0-100% on the Y axis and quarters on the X-axis. The source data includes:

```
{ 
 date: '2015 Q1',
 numerator: 55,
 denominator: 105,
 percent:52 
}
```

When plotting, the series data is specified as `[52, '2015 Q1']` and displays on the chart correctly. However, when I hover over the data point, I would like to display the raw numerator and denominator as well as the percentage.

Is there any way for me to include additional meta data in the series data?

** Note for this example I am simplifying the quarter logic. It is actually specified in milliseconds as per the flot specs **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your example data should be `['2015 Q1', 52]`, x value goes first.

And second, you can use arrays with more then two values for the datapoints, for example `['2015 Q1', 52, 55, 105]` and then use the third and forth value in your tooltips (flot will ignore them when drawing the chart itself for line and point charts).

Example code for the tooltip:

```
function bindHover() {
    $(document).on('plothover', '#chart', function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            if (prevPoint != item.dataIndex) {
                prevPoint = item.dataIndex;
                $('#tooltip').remove();

                var tooltipString = item.series.name + ': ' + item.datapoint[0];
                tooltipString += '/' + item.datapoint[1];
                tooltipString += '<br/>' + item.series.data[item.dataIndex][2];
                tooltipString += '/' + item.series.data[item.dataIndex][3];
                showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, tooltipString);
            }
        }
        else {
            $('#tooltip').remove();
            prevPoint = null;
        }
    });
}
```